# XMLHttpRequest problem in BlackBerry 10 (QML)

Tags: qt, xmlhttprequest, qml, blackberry, blackberry-10

Hello a have a problem with my javascript.
Can you help me?
Thank everybody.

When I have:

```
var url = "http://naucse-python.now.sh" // error -> Redirect to http://naucse-python.now.sh/ (308)

var url = "https://naucse-python.now.sh" // nothing is displayed
```

When I have:

```
var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" // everything is OK

var url = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1" // nothing is displayed
```

```
// main.qml
import bb.cascades 1.4

Page {

    function sendRequest() {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        var url = "http://naucse-python.now.sh"
        //var url = "http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1"

        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            //if (xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                //if (xhr.status === 200) {

                    console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    textArea.text = xhr.responseText;
                //}
            //}
        };
        xhr.open("GET", url, true);
        xhr.send();
    }

    Container {

        TextArea {
            id: textArea
        }
    }

    onCreationCompleted: {
        sendRequest()
    }
}
```

Comment: I just ran this on Ubuntu 19.04 and it works fine. For both 'http' and 'https' i received ` {
  "userId": 1,
  "id": 1,
  "title": "delectus aut autem",
  "completed": false
}` Be sure that you've installed OpenSSL correctly.

Comment: Sorry, I did not write all specifications. When I use those url in my web browser (PC - elementary OS) everything is OK. But I use those url in Momentics IDE. I have the problem  there.

Comment: I was running it in Qt Creator when it worked for me